# Getting some combinations of given list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, tail-recursion

I am trying to figure out how to use tail recursion to divide given list with this pattern. For instance  list is equal to [1,2,3,4].

```
clause([1,2,3,4],X). would return:
X = [1,2,3,4]
X = [1,2,3]
X = [2,3,4]
X = [1,2]
X = [2,3]
X = [3,4]
X = [1]
X = [2]
X = [3]
X = [4]
```

I would be grateful for giving any advice on it.

Answer (score 3):

You need a new name, `clause/2` is already taken by a built-in predicate.

```
list_sublist(Xs, Ys) :-
   Ys = [_|_],
   phrase(( ..., seq(Ys), ...), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

?- list_sublist([1,2,3,4], Xs).
   Xs = [1]
;  Xs = [1,2]
;  Xs = [1,2,3]
;  Xs = [1,2,3,4]
;  Xs = [2]
;  Xs = [2,3]
;  Xs = [2,3,4]
;  Xs = [3]
;  Xs = [3,4]
;  Xs = [4]
;  false.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SWISH sample](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/lists.pl) that shows how to obtain the functionality composing simpler patterns:

```
suffix(Xs, Ys) :-
    append(_, Ys, Xs).

prefix(Xs, Ys) :-
    append(Ys, _, Xs).

sublist_not_empty(Xs, [Y|Ys]) :-
    suffix(Xs, Zs),
    prefix(Zs, [Y|Ys]).
```

I've added the 'not empty' condition, since [Y|Ys] cannot match an empty list.